# Magento2 Newsletter Grid custom column filter not working

Tags: grid, admin, magento2, newsletter

I have added new column in newsletter grid in Magento2.2.5 with override newsletter_subscriber_block.xml in my custom module, but somehow filter is not working for new column. Please find below code of newsletter grid i have override in my custom module..

```
<referenceBlock name="adminhtml.newslettrer.subscriber.grid.columnSet">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Urgency</argument>
                    <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">urgency</argument>
                    <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                    <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="withinweek" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">With in 3 Weeks</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="afterweek" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">After 3 Weeks</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-urgency</argument>
                    <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-urgency</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Please replace the image of your code with your code in text format. [This is a good explanation](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) as to why (I've not voted).

Comment: i have done as per your suggestion